# Query on use of \w in reqex

Tags: regex, perl

Below perl script is printing the whole string as an output,But I was expecting output as Perl.I am new to perl as well as regex.Can someone please explain me why I am not getting the expected output.

```
my $txt='I am learning Perl'; 
$txt=~/(\w+)$/;
print $txt;
```

OutPut;

`I am learning Perl`

Output I was expecting:

`Perl`

As per my knowledge the output should be a word containing one or more alphanumeric characters and the search for the pattern begins from the end.I don't understand where I am wrong here .

Comment: replace "print $txt" by "print $1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression match doesn't modify the variable. It returns either a list of matches or a boolean depending on the context.

Use it in list context to capture the matches.

```
my $txt='I am learning Perl'; 
my ($match) = $txt=~/(\w+)$/;
print $match;
```

Comment: Can there be a list of matches if the regex doesn't have a `/g` modifier?

Comment: @TimPietzcker — Yes, since there can be (a) multiple capturing groups and (b) a list can have exactly one item in it and still be a list. (This is an example of the latter)

Comment: Since it returns a list, if you changed the above code to be in scalar context (i.e. `my $match =` instead of `my ($match) =`) then the output would be `1` (the length of the list) instead of `Perl` (the value of the scalar inside the list).

Comment: @Quentin That is wrong. `m//` in scalar context returns a boolean result, not a length.

Comment: Whoops, so it does. Shows how often I use capturing regex in scalar context.

Answer (score 2):

`$txt` is not modified by the match operation.

But you get a new variable `$1` which contains the contents of the first capturing group (which contains `'Perl'` in your example.

Comment: Don't use `$&`; it slows down every regex match everywhere.

Comment: @melpomene: Interesting. How does it slow it down?

Comment: @TimPietzcker : To quote [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): "The use of this variable anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on all regular expression matches. To avoid this penalty, you can extract the same substring by using `@-`. Starting with Perl 5.10, you can use the `/p` match flag and the `${^MATCH}` variable to do the same thing for particular match operations."

Comment: `$&` is global, so if the parser sees you using it anywhere, every single match operation has to set it (because perl can't tell at compile time how you're going to use it). That means every single regex match will create a copy of the target string.

Comment: @melpomene, Zaid: Thanks for the explanation. Strange that this isn't true for `$1`. I must admit I fail to understand why `$&` is global and `$1` isn't...

Comment: @TimPietzcker `$1` only needs to be set if the regex contains `(...)`. `$&` has no such restriction.